# Gulpjs concatenation and file names

Tags: javascript, gulp

I am looking for a way to insert the file name as a comment to each file in the stream.
So after all you'll have a comment line with the file path, in the concatenated destination file.

What it does right now:

```
pseudocode: concat(file1, file2) 
# output: 
# contents of file 1
# contents of file 2
```

What I want to achieve:

```
pseudocode: concat(add_comments(file1, file2))
# output: 
# // file1
# contents of file 1
# // file2
# contents of file 2
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [the `gulp-wrap` plugin](https://www.npmjs.org/package/gulp-wrap/) to prepend the file name before concatenating:

```js
var wrap = require('gulp-wrap');

// in your task...
    return gulp.src('src/**/*.js')
        .pipe(wrap('//<%= file.path %>\n<%= contents %>'))
        .pipe(concat('output.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('build'))
```

The wrap plugin allows you to wrap the contents of an item in the stream with a lodash (or underscore) template.  It provides `contents` and `file.*` properties automatically.

The template I created is very simple: it outputs two slashes for the comment, the file's `path`, a newline, and then outputs the same contents as passed in.

Comment: Thanks! Now, how can I get the file name and not the full path? "file.name" did not work. Also, how could discover what all of the properties in the FILE object are?

Comment: @brOlite - `file` seems to be a vinyl object, see https://www.npmjs.com/package/vinyl. Using `file.relative` worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

I did it with [gulp-insert](https://github.com/rschmukler/gulp-insert).
It has a "transform" function where you are given the file contents, and the Vinyl file object, and you return the new contents.  So you can do this:

```
.pipe(insert.transform(function(contents, file){
    return '// ' + file.path + '\n' + contents;
}));
```

Comment: Not to say the accepted answer isn't a solution but I found gulp-insert to be much more flexible for my use case.